View JSON formatting broken in SharePoint Online - Any changes from Microsoft?
I'm not sure if anyone is experiencing this. I have some view formatting that I have applied on my SharePoint list but it's all appearing weird this morning. I can't get to reduce the height.
Has anything changed from Microsoft?
The below just used to be a small card with letters in it. Now suddenly it's very large.
How can I reduce the card's height?

My JSON below:
{
  "$schema": "https://developer.microsoft.com/json-schemas/sp/v2/tile-formatting.schema.json",
  "height": 25,
  "width": 53,
  "hideSelection": true,
  "fillHorizontally": true,
  "formatter": {
    "elmType": "div",
    "attributes": {
      "class": "sp-card-container"
    },
    "children": [
      {
        "elmType": "span",
        "attributes": {
          "class": "sp-card-defaultClickButton",
          "role": "presentation"
        },
        "customRowAction": {
          "action": "defaultClick"
        }
      },
      {
        "elmType": "div",
        "attributes": {
          "class": "ms-bgColor-white sp-css-borderColor-neutralLight sp-card-borderHighlight sp-card-subContainer"
        },
        "children": [
          {
            "elmType": "div",
            "attributes": {
              "class": "sp-card-lastTextColumnContainer"
            },
            "children": [
              {
                "elmType": "p",
                "attributes": {
                  "title": "[$Title]",
                  "class": "ms-fontColor-neutralPrimary sp-card-content sp-card-highlightedContent"
                },
                "txtContent": "=[$Title]",
                "style": {
                  "text-align": "left",
                  "font-size": "0.8em",
                  "font-weight": "bold"
                }
              }
            ]
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
}


I have the same issue since yesterday :(

I have exactly the same. Better open a ticket with Microsoft.

Any luck at your end gus. I have one client that seems to have een restored and the other nothing yet

This would likely be better as a comment, but I don't have a high enough reputation in this StackExchange.
I've upvoted this Microsoft feedback entry that someone started pertaining to this issue and suggest others do the same: https://feedbackportal.microsoft.com/feedback/idea/d638bd7b-a496-ef11-95f5-6045bdbc7c39
I think reporting an issue within SharePoint is also a good option, but I'm not sure if it adds you to a queue or what happens to those.
It appears anyone using the tiles JSON formatting is having an issue.  I doubt it's intentional—I think just making them aware of this issue is the best we can do at this time.
EDIT:
Microsoft appears to have fixed this issue. I personally consider this issue resolved.

Hope they get it fixed soon

I think MS have fixed it

@naijacoder I agree. It appears MS has fixed it
