JSON Formatting In Views
My gallery views that are JSON formatted are all of a sudden not displaying correctly, although nothing has changed and the views have not been edited. I can create a new Gallery view, but the JSON is not responsive.I'm guessing this is a MS issue, but is anyone else experiencing similar?

Similar to https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/314638/view-json-formatting-broken-in-sharepoint-online-any-changes-from-microsoft

Whether the list change to new experience?
